# How to refresh image every 5 seconds?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.forms and I need to display a webcam image with an automatic refresh every 5 seconds.

XAML:

```
<Image RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}" RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}">
    <Image.Source>
        <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding WebCam1Url}" 
            CacheValidity="0" 
            CachingEnabled="false"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

View Model:

```
public String WebCam1Url
{
    get { return webcam1url; }
    set
    {
        webcam1url = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("WebCam1Url");
    }
}
```

The image is displayed but it's never refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Device.StartTimer to update your binding "WebCam1Url":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.starttimer?view=xamarin-forms

I think you have to change the value of the binding at every update to make it works, using a fake querystring parameter like **?update=xxxx** where **xxx** is a random string wich you have to change every 5 seconds inside the Device.StartTimer method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below method in OnAppearing() method :

```
 Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
            {
                //your uri is update here but you need every time new uri so you have to fetch it from anywhere
                return true;
            });
```